# Prestashop filter date_add in webservice

Tags: prestashop

i'm new, and i've a problem with webservice.

when i try to retrieve customers filtering by date_add i get this error:

```
<message><![CDATA[This filter does not exist. Did you mean: "deleted"? The full list is: "id", "id_default_group", "id_lang", "newsletter_date_add", "ip_registration_newsletter", "last_passwd_gen", "secure_key", "deleted", "passwd", "lastname", "firstname", "email", "id_gender", "birthday", "newsletter", "optin", "website", "company", "siret", "ape", "outstanding_allow_amount", "show_public_prices", "id_risk", "max_payment_days", "active", "note", "is_guest", "id_shop", "id_shop_group"]]></message>
```

this is my code:

```
$yesterday = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() - 60 * 60 * 24);

$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);

// Qui imposto le opzion dell'array per il Webservice: in questo caso i clienti e setto che il formato è json
$opt = array( 'resource' => 'customers',
                        'filter[date_add]' => '['.$yesterday.']&date=1',
                        'display'  => 'full',
                        'output_format' => 'JSON'
                        );

// faccio la chiamata
$xml = $webService->get($opt);
```

I'm stuck, I do not know what to do !!! any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Customer class webservice parameters, there is no date_add:

```
protected $webserviceParameters = array(
        'fields' => array(
            'id_default_group' => array('xlink_resource' => 'groups'),
            'id_lang' => array('xlink_resource' => 'languages'),
            'newsletter_date_add' => array(),
            'ip_registration_newsletter' => array(),
            'last_passwd_gen' => array('setter' => null),
            'secure_key' => array('setter' => null),
            'deleted' => array(),
            'passwd' => array('setter' => 'setWsPasswd'),
        ),
        'associations' => array(
            'groups' => array('resource' => 'group'),
        )
    );
```

If you have access to the server installation, you could add the `date_add` field to the webserviceParameters.
Or the function getWebserviceObjectList to change the behavour.

If you don't have access to the server installation, you can use the `sort` to get the latest customers until you reach the one you already have. You can use with `limit` to use in a foreach or while loop.

EDIT After some testing and inspecting what was going on:
First, it's we don't need to add the field `date_add` to the `$webserviceParameters`.

The request should be:

```
$opt = array( 'resource' => 'customers',
               'filter[date_add]' => '['.$begin.','.$finish.']',
               'date' => 1,
               'display'  => 'full',
               'output_format' => 'JSON'
              );
```

If you only add one date to the filter it will try to match only that date.

Then you need to change the PSWebServiceLibrary.php in line 284 and add the field 'date':

```
$params = array('filter', 'display', 'sort', 'limit', 'id_shop', 'id_group_shop', 'date');
```

Now it should work. I tested myself.

EDIT 2:
This is my full test, after changing the the line i mentioned in PSWebserviceLibrary.php, this retrieves my customers with date_add in the interval date.

```
<?php
require_once( 'PSWebServiceLibrary.php' );

echo 'starting<br />'.PHP_EOL;

try {
    // creating web service access
    $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(MY_BASE_URL, WS_KEY, true);

    $yesterday = date("Y-m-d", time() - 60 * 60 * 24);
    $begin = date("Y-m-d", time() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);

    $opt = array( 'resource' => 'customers',
                        'filter[date_add]' => '['.$begin.','.$yesterday.']',
                        'date' => 1,
                        'display'  => 'full',
                        'output_format' => 'JSON'
                        );

    //Retrieving the XML data
    $xml = $webService->get($opt);
}
catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex) {
    // Shows a message related to the error
    echo 'Other error: <br />' . $ex->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: have you any idea?

Comment: you have `'date=1'` inside the `filter[date_add]`. try adding to the array instead. because in the webservice if not `(!empty($this->urlFragments['date']) && $this->urlFragments['date'])` it will remove the date_add from the available_fields

Comment: I don't want to be boring, but I still have the same error

Comment: no problem. just edited again, adding my working example. don't forget to change the PSWebserviceLibrary.php as mentioned.

Comment: great works perfectly ... thank you so much, an invaluable aid

Answer (score 0):

first of all: thanks

I modified as your indication, but the result does not change, still gives me the same error.

```
protected $webserviceParameters = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'id_default_group' => array('xlink_resource' => 'groups'),
        'id_lang' => array('xlink_resource' => 'languages'),
        'newsletter_date_add' => array(),
        'ip_registration_newsletter' => array(),
        'last_passwd_gen' => array('setter' => null),
        'secure_key' => array('setter' => null),
        'deleted' => array(),
        'passwd' => array('setter' => 'setWsPasswd'),
/** inizio modifica aggiunta per il webservice */
        'date_add' => array(),
/** fine della modifica */
    ),
    'associations' => array(
        'groups' => array('resource' => 'group'),
    )
);
```

I can not understand